# jenkins - archive artifacts ‘*’ doesn’t match anything

Tags: jenkins, artifacts

I'm trying to set up a step to archive artifacts and I want to archive everything however specifying * does not work. Jenkins comes up with 
‘*’ doesn’t match anything

if I run the job regardless the job fails and logs show:
ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "*". Configuration error?
ERROR: ‘*’ doesn’t match anything

I tried using ** too but that came back with the same errors

Comment: Refer to https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17351                           It states that artifacts outside the workspace cannot be archived

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run Jenkins on Windows host, you must use `*.*` for everything

Comment: Try using `**/*`

Comment: ‘**/*’ doesn’t match anything: ‘**’ exists but not ‘**/*’

Comment: that also fails with the same error ERROR: ‘**/*’ doesn’t match anything: ‘**’ exists but not ‘**/*’ | ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "**/*". Configuration error?

Comment: Could you please check your job's workspace if it is empty? If there are no files, Jenkins will fail to archive artifacts

Comment: there are no files there

Comment: try putting something in the workspace, manually or via `echo "hello world" > output.txt`

Comment: that worked. I can see output.txt in the workspace directory

Comment: Inside Jenkins workspace folder I have a folder called Tests, and inside it I have a file called tests.xml. So how would my path look like? because the most obvious thing, 'Tests/tests.xml', doesn't work.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and **/* doesn't seems to work for me.

Answer (score 10):

Here is what to check for:

- archive artifacts will only work in the workspace and fails outside
- the path should be a relative path in the workspace and doesnt start with "." :

  ```
  archiveArtifacts artifacts: "build/**"
  archiveArtifacts artifacts: "./build/**"   // Fails
  archiveArtifacts artifacts: "$workspace/build/**"    // Fails
  ```
- " *"  matches any file in the directory, ** will match everything including dir and subdirectories, **/.log will matches all files in all subdirectories with potfix
- depending on if it s a windows or linux node, you will want to express your path differently

Answer (score 4):

`*` only matches `any files` in workspace, if the artifacts you want to archive is in some subdirectories, you need the pattern like `**/*.sh` to match all files in all subdirectories with postfix `.sh`.

Comment: I did say I need to archive everything

Comment: Then it's `**/*`.

Comment: that also fails with the same error ERROR: ‘**/*’ doesn’t match anything: ‘**’ exists but not ‘**/*’ | ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "**/*". Configuration error?

Comment: That's very funny, I'm pretty sure `**/*` is working because I tried before posting my answer. BTW, did you config it with quote like `'**/*'` or `"**/*"`? I met the same problem when I tried it this way.